# Remove from all and addclass to selected with ng-click in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have event when I click the text div1 for example will be bold, and remove bold from the other selected, I tried with `addClass` but it did not work. How can I resolve this? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/13575/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id='1_1' ng-click="addClassToSelected($event)">div1</div>
<div id='1_2' ng-click="addClassToSelected($event)">div1</div>
<div id='1_3' ng-click="addClassToSelected($event)">div1</div>
<div id='1_4' ng-click="addClassToSelected($event)">div1</div>
<div id='1_5' ng-click="addClassToSelected($event)">div1</div>
<div id='1_6' ng-click="addClassToSelected($event)">div1</div>
<div id='1_7' ng-click="addClassToSelected($event)">div1</div>
```

**Angular:**

```
$scope.addClassSelected = function(event){
            var id =event.target.id ;
            $('#'+id).addClass("bold-selected");
        };
```

**CSS:**

```
.bold-selected {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Could you add a jsfiddle so we can try it out?

Comment: are you rendering this `div` using `ng-repeat`?

Comment: you should use `ng-repeat` then angular will make your life easy,,

Answer (score 0):

You really should be reading up on how to get away from jquery when working with angular. Start at this topic: ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Here is the answer to your question though. First off your dom should look like this if it's going to be something repeated:

```
<div 
    data-ng-class="{
        'bold-selected': option.id == selectedId
       }"
    data-ng-repeat="option in data" 
    data-ng-click="addClassToSelected(option.id)"
    id="1_{{ data.id }}">
    div1
</div>
```

Second, this is what your controller would look like instead:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{ id: 1 },{ id: 2 },{ id: 3 },{ id: 4 },{ id: 5 },{ id: 6 },{ id: 7 }];
    $scope.selectedId = false;
    $scope.addClassToSelected = function(id){
        $scope.selectedId = id;
    }
}
```

Here's the jsFiddle of the final version: http://jsfiddle.net/w2hfourg/

Comment: i just want to add a class to selected no ng-repeat, this is just a example

Comment: in my case  option.id is the div#id it self

Comment: Why do you have #ids on divs to begin with?

Comment: data-ng-class="{
        'bold-selected': myDivId == selectedId
       }"
what i make in myDivId  ??

Comment: you just make my life so hard

Comment: You're not really using angular, you're making your own life hard by trying to incorporate both it and jquery. My question was why do your divs have ids on them? Why do they need them? In general angular applications only have ids for styling purposes.

Comment: can i use ng-show without id and without ng-repeat ! i dont like to use jQuery i try just select the div that i click it in

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/zvLvg/) the answer

```
<span id='1' ng-class='{"myclass":tog==1}' ng-click='tog=1'>span 1</span>
<span id='2' ng-class='{"myclass":tog==2}' ng-click='tog=2'>span 2</span>
```

Comment: You should add some explanation about what this is doing and why it solves the problem.

Comment: i add a  jsfiddle link